# How to return result of an Oracle stored procedure to a shell script

Tags: oracle, shell

I have a oracle procedure proc1 which adds two values and gives the result.I have to call this procedure from shell and show its result back to the shell.I am able to call that procedure from the shell,but it just shows that PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.But the result is not coming to the shell .

i am doing this to call the procedure from shell...

```
$  echo "execute proc1(10,10);"|sqlplus -s system/xxxxx@orcl
```

This is the procedure which is running fine .

```
  create or replace procedure proc1
 (N1 in number,N2 in number) is
 begin
 dbms_output.put_line(N1+N2);
 end;
 /
```

I need the output in the shell .Anyone plese help.

Comment: This has been asked *numerous* times.  Attempt a search before posting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PL SQL output is not getting displayed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390054/pl-sql-output-is-not-getting-displayed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am aware there is another answer showing how to use `set serveroutput on` and the procedure call on separate lines, however I am writing this answer as a *one-liner* to do the same thing.

Bascially you need to shove this into sqlplus:

```
set serveroutput on
execute proc1(10,10);
```

You might at first think this can be done on one line, separated with a semi-colon.

```
set serveroutput on; execute proc1(10,10);
```

However that doesn't work - you really need a newline character.

So the trick is to also use `-e` flag with `echo`, which can give you a newline with `\n`.

Using `head -1` trims everyting but the line containing the procedure result.

Final one-line answer:

```
echo -e "set serveroutput on\n execute proc1(10,10);"|sqlplus -s system/xxxxx@orcl| head -1
```

P.S. I editted your question to remove the password :)